# How to estimate average user review ratings?

Tags: distributions, bayesian, estimation

For example, in Amazon Books

- book A : 1 rating of 5. Average rating of 5
- book B : 50 ratings. Average rating of 4.5

If use naive average, then book A is higher than book B. However, we all know that this comes from in-sufficient data.

How can we give book A a proper rating, if the data is not enough?

---

I find revalant writings from

- http://www.evanmiller.org/ranking-items-with-star-ratings.html
- https://fulmicoton.com/posts/bayesian_rating/

However, both seem a bit complex from my view, and hard to implement.

I aggregate data from Amazon, and find there is a distribution of the ratings

[image]

So I'm thingking a naive-empirical approach

- Decide after 100 ratings, the avg rating becomes stable
- For book with < 100 rating, the rating is weighted avg between population avg and its rating. e.g., `(1-w2)*4.6 + w2*rating`
- The `w2` should be a function of power-law like distribution, so the ratings number from 1 to 2 will change more as from 99 to 100.

Comment: If the two above links are too complicated, I'm afraid it would be hard to find something simpler... What is the problem with implementing them? This can be done in SQL.

Comment: Association Rule Learning deals with this by having both "support" (or frequency) and "confidence" scores for each rule. You could do something similar here.